# If a set of vectors is not generating, its dual/ biorthogonal system is not unique.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

This is a question from a Linear Algebra textbook I am studying from, I can't figure out how to even start it, any help would be much appreciated:

$\{v_{1}, ..., v_{r}\}$ is a system of vectors in $V$ such that there exists a system of *linear functionals* $\{v_{1}^{v},...,v_{r}^{v}\}$ defined by :

$$
 v_{i}^{v}(v_{j})=\delta_{ij} =
    \begin{cases}
            1, &         \text{if } i=j,\\
            0, &         \text{if } i\neq j.
    \end{cases}
$$

Show that if $\{v_{1}, ..., v_{r}\}$ are not generating then the dual / biorthogonal system $\{v_{1}^{v},...,v_{r}^{v}\}$ is not unique.

Again, any help is much appreciated. I understand what the dual space and dual basis are, and I've proved that that any system of vectors with a dual system must be linearly independent (by definition of dual basis and linearity), but can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\operatorname{span}(\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_r\})$. Since $S\varsubsetneq V$, there is some $w\in V\setminus S$. Since the set $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_r,w\}$ is linearly independent, there are linear functionals $\varphi_i^w\colon V\longrightarrow k$ (where $k$ is the field that you are working with) such that $\varphi_i^w(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$ and that $\varphi_i^w(w)=1$. All these $\varphi_i^w$'s change if $w$ gets replaced by some $\lambda w$, for some $\lambda\in k\setminus\{0\}$. But all of them have the property that $\varphi_i^w(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: if $V*$ is the dual space, why is it spanned by the vectors in $V$?

Comment: I did not mention $V^*$; I called $V^\star$ to a subspace of $V$ ($\star\ne*$). But I will change my notation.

Comment: I completely understand! I just misunderstood the notation, thank you for your clear answer.